# DOB Format from json response and set in EDITTEXT

Tags: android, json, simpledateformat

- I am getting DOB from json response like this :

  12��81990
- I want to format it like this

  12/8/1990
- What i have tried :

```java
SimpleDateFormat hh_mm_ss = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a MM/dd");

try {

   hh_mm_ss.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-05:00"));
   Date date = hh_mm_ss.parse(arraylist.get(position).get("createddate"));
   hh_mm_ss.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
   String formattedDate = dateFormat2.format(date);
   tvPostTime.setText(formattedDate);

} catch (ParseException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the format of the date you are getting in JSON and format in the 1st line `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` is same? I have tried your code and its working fine for me.

Comment: no,, i was trying that code , but it wont working. i simply  want to formate in dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: The date format you are getting from json should match the format of hh_mm_ss. Change the date format of dateFormat2 `hh:mm a MM/dd` in the 2nd line to `dd/mm/yyyy`

Comment: Unparseable date: "12��81990"  , getting this errot

Comment: It clearly says that you cannot parse that date as it have some special characters ��. You are not getting a proper date format. And change the format from `dd/mm/yyyy` to `dd/MM/yyyy`